# sqlite index on strings columns

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a query. It's taking 1100 ms which I don't think it should.

```
select * from PageInfo where url = @url OR url like @url2
```

The url are `/sub/id` and `/sub2/id/thing`. I have an index on `pageinfo(url)`. The body of the page is about ~10k and this sample got me 1120ms for 2 rows (<20k). It feels wrong it takes that long. I should be able to get both those pages over the network in less then that time.

What can I do to speed things up? I have an index, i'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Just do a [`VACUUM`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) and see if you get any performance improvement.

Comment: @Habib: This is taking some time to run and the journal is only 2kb... The filesize is the same but it only been a few mins

Comment: VACUUM usually takes some time, I am not sure why it is taking so much time on a 2kb file.

Comment: Why are you using `like`? The index will not be used for the `like` part of the query. Can you use index compatible comparisons such as `=` or `BETWEEN` or `in`?

Comment: @Habib: Nah the journal is 2kb, the main db is 4.5gb. Now its growing it took 4+ mins to figure things out. Its now at 2.5gb and rising

Comment: @DougCurrie: Well to be exact the url where i use like is `/sub2/1234/thing?page=2` so i want to capture all the pages. idk if it uses the index but it should as there isn't a reason not to since it doesn't start with `%`

Comment: @Habib: It seems slightly bigger (a few mb) and 50ms slower.

Comment: @acidzombie24, really after VACUUM , thats new for me

Comment: @acidzombie24: you can see the query plan with `explain`; it does not use the index for your query; note that the presence of `%` is unknown to the statement compiler since it would be part of the supplied argument

Comment: @Habib: It could just be because I am reading a different part of the database and this section happens to return a few more rows (pages). But yeah its jumping between 10 and 50 ms slower usually around 40ms

Comment: @Habib: Dougs answer is right on the money

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `like` will prevent use of the index.

Compare

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from PageInfo where url = @url OR url like @url2;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE PageInfo (~500000 rows)
sqlite>
```

to

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from PageInfo where url = @url OR url between @url2 and @url3;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE PageInfo USING INDEX pi (url=?) (~10 rows)
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE PageInfo USING INDEX pi (url>? AND url<?) (~31250 rows)
sqlite>
```

You should use `between` and construct arguments to the query for `@url2` and `@url3` such as

```
/sub2/1234/thing?page=0
```

and

```
/sub2/1234/thing?page=99999999
```

Comment: Holy crap that's amazing! its taking 0ms and I saw a 17ms here and there.

Comment: It takes 2 mins to do what it use to take over 30. Thank you

Comment: Instead of `/sub2/1234/thing?page=99999999`, a tilde worked for me as its sorted alphabetically after digits:

`/sub2/1234/thing?page=~`